# open a pdf with word vba in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to `vba` and I have been trying to open a PDF file with `MS word` 2016 in order to copy the data and populate cells in `Excel`, I have been able to open the PDF and copy the data but I have found it tricky to get the data I need and to populate the cells in `Excel`. I was wondering if this was possible to code in VBA via `excel`.

thanks

Comment: Please show the code you have up to now, especially one opening PDF and copying data to MS Word.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I can currently only open a PDF file and copy the content from that file, I am wondering if I can open the PDF file with MS Word by using VBA in Excel. The code I have so far is as follows:

Comment: Edit your question, don't add you code in comments here..

Comment: Excel also has VBA coding abilities. Look for the developer tab in your ribbon. It might be switched off, in that case just google how to switch it on.

Comment: I am using developer mode in Excel currently, I would like to open a PDF file with MS Word by using VBA code in excel, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4):

This solution requires a reference to the Word library to be set in Excel (Tools,references)

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String
Dim t As Excel.Range
s = "\\my path\my file.pdf"
Dim wd As New Word.Application
Dim mydoc As Word.Document
Set mydoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=s, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False)
Dim wr As Word.Range
Set wr = mydoc.Paragraphs(1).Range
wr.WholeStory   
Set t = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
wr.Copy
t.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
mydoc.Close False
wd.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, was a great help to me, I was missing the Word Library, works fine now

Comment: Getting an error "Class not registered" in the line " Set mydoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filename:=s, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False) "

Comment: Should be `wd.Documents.Open` rather than `Word.Documents.Open` based on `wd` Word application handler